# Run the jtidy tests

Tags: jtidy

I'm trying to run the unit tests in the jtidy source but I'm getting this exception. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm guessing the package folder is not setup right.

> java.lang.Error: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle
>   for base name org/w3c/tidy/TidyMessages, locale en_US     at
>   org.w3c.tidy.Report.(Report.java:649)     at
>   org.w3c.tidy.Tidy.(Tidy.java:135)   at
>   org.w3c.tidy.TidyTestCase.setUp(TidyTestCase.java:153)    at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding creating the srcc folder for \src\test\resources